# How to use factory.SelfAttribute with factory.Sequence?

Tags: django, factory-boy

I have  model like so:

```
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I am trying to build a factory:

```
class ItemGroupFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemGroup

    category = FuzzyChoice(['category1', 'category2'])
    name = Sequence(lambda n: "%s%d" % (SelfAttribute("category"), n))
```

The problem is, this does not work, while testing I get:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Data too long for column 'name' at row 1
```

So how to use SelfAttribute with Sequence?
I am using:

```
Django  1.8.14
djangorestframework 3.4.6
fake-factory    0.5.3   
mysql-connector-python  2.1.3
factory-boy 2.7.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was this was an incorrect way to do it. For sucha a task, that is creating sequences based on attributes I shoud've used `LazyAttributeSequence`. Like so:

```
class ItemGroupFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemGroup

    category = FuzzyChoice(['gadżety', 'jedzenie'])
    name = LazyAttributeSequence(lambda o,n: "%s%d" % (o.category, n))
```